# Cannot get the right response using python requests' post method

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, python-requests

I'm trying to automate the recovery of data from [this website](http://www.bmfbovespa.com.br/en_us/services/market-data/historical-data/derivatives-market/file-history/) (The one I want is " 
BVBG.086.01 PriceReport"). Checking with firefox, I found out that the request URL to which the POST is made is "http://www.bmf.com.br/arquivos1/lum-download_ipn.asp", and the parameters are:

```
hdnStatus: "ativo"
chkArquivoDownload_ativo    "28"
txtDataDownload_ativo   "09/02/2018"
imgSubmeter "Download"
txtDataDownload_externo_ativo   [3]
    0   "25/08/2017"
    1   "25/08/2017"
    2   "25/08/2017"
```

So, if I use hurl.it to make the request, the response is the correct 302 redirect (Pointing to a FTP URL where the requested files are, something like "Location: /FTP/Temp/10981738/Download.ex_"). ([Example of the request here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mYUv.png)).

So I've tried doing the same with with the following code (Using python's library "requests", and I have tried both versions of request_body, trying to put it into the "data" parameter of the post method)

```
request_url = "http://www.bmf.com.br/arquivos1/lum-download_ipn.asp"
request_headers = {
    "Host": "www.bmf.com.br",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "Referer": "http://www.bmf.com.br/arquivos1/lum-arquivos_ipn.asp?idioma=pt-BR&status=ativo",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Content-Length": "236",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1"
}
# request_body = "hdnStatus=ativo&chkArquivoDownload_ativo=28&txtDataDownload_ativo=09/02/2018&imgSubmeter=Download&txtDataDownload_externo_ativo=25/08/2017&txtDataDownload_externo_ativo=25/08/2017&txtDataDownload_externo_ativo=25/08/2017"
request_body = {
    "hdnStatus" : "ativo",
    "chkArquivoDownload_ativo": "28",
    "txtDataDownload_ativo": "09/02/2018",
    "imgSubmeter": "Download",
    "txtDataDownload_externo_ativo": ["25/08/2017", "25/08/2017", "25/08/2017"]
}

result_query = post(request_url, request_body, headers=request_headers)
# result_query = post(request_url, data=request_body, headers=request_headers)

for red in result_query.history:
    print(BeautifulSoup(red.content, "lxml"))
    print()

print(result_query.url)
```

And what I get is the following response:

```
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head>
<body><h1>Object Moved</h1>This object may be found <a href="lumarquivos_ipn.asp">here</a>.</body>
</html>

<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head>
<body><h1>Object Moved</h1>This object may be found <a href="/arquivos1/lum-arquivos_ipn.asp?idioma=pt-BR&amp;status=">here</a>.</body>
</html>

<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head>
<body><h1>Object Moved</h1>This object may be found <a href="/arquivos1/lum-arquivos_ipn.asp?idioma=pt-BR&amp;status=ativo">here</a>.</body>
</html>

http://www.bmf.com.br/arquivos1/lum-arquivos_ipn.asp?idioma=pt-BR&status=ativo
```

And not the one I wanted (Which should point to the location of the file). What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It worked when I removed every header key, except Referer and Content-Type, which, as I tested on hurl.it, are the only two necessary headers. Still don't understand why that happened though.